# arara skripting to convert svg to pdf through inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape, arara

I read about the arara cli and some scripting capabilities and im wondering if its possible to make arara use inkscape to convert svg to pdf before includeing them with `\includegraphics`.

A frend showed me how this works with `make` but in my case i can not use `make` because of serveral usage of `input`.

arara works already, and thats why im seeking for a automaton...

not a working MWE but a idea of what im looking for, see line 4:

```
% !TEX root = ./main.tex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: command: if *.svg found("@{ return getCommand('inkscape -D -z --file=$1.svg --export-pdf=$1.pdf --export-latex') }")
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: {extensions: [aux,bib,bbl,blg,glg,glo,gls,idx,ilg,ind,ist,log,lot,out,xml,toc,top,tui,mp]}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{vector.svg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you know about the `svg` package which would do exactly this workflow for you? (needs `-shell-escape` for compiling)

Comment: if you convert the svg to pdf first, then the latex document should include the pdf file not the svg file via `\includegraphics`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thats correct. But im seeking for a automated version.

Comment: @novski but as you have it, if arara does the conversion it will be done before pdftex starts so the tex document should reference a pdf file not an svg file.

Comment: @samcarter i didn't! thanks for that link. I tried to call -shell-escape like this: % arara: pdflatex -shell-escape but that does not work. i don't understand the help in the arara manual so do you know how to call -shell-escape with arara?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle correct. But im seeking a way to convert it with arara first... or a way to make arara use svg package..

Comment: so either use `\includegraphics` and include a pdf or use the svg package and use `\includesvg`. In the latter case you don't need arara or just use a simple rule that calls pdftex.

Comment: im using arara for several different reasons. there must be a way to use arara with --shell-escape

Comment: @novski To use shell-escape with arara: `% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}`